# How do I generate specs for existing controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have several controllers already set up. Now I want to start writing spec tests for them. Is there a command that generates the spec files automatically? I know rails does this for new resources, but I don't know if it does it for existing controllers/models too.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
rails g rspec:controller ControllerName
```

When it asks you to override the existing controller, type `n`.

Comment: This ONLY generates the spec file for the controller. If you want the associated files, such as helpers or factories, then you want: `rails g controller ControllerName -s` The -s at the end will cause it to skip any existing files so you don't have to bother with the question regarding overriding anything.

Comment: this works for model also? `rspec:model`? this exists on rspec 1?

Comment: Would something namespaced within `rspec` normally try to create a controller? Or are you thinking of what `rails g controller ControllerName` do?

Comment: This is an answer from 5 years ago which probably held true then.

Answer (score 10):

There are two options. If you want an empty spec file, you could try with:

```
rails g rspec:controller ControllerName
```

Now, if you want a spec file with initial specs for a basic REST controller, try with:

```
rails g rspec:scaffold ControllerName
```

Answer (score 4):

If you've configured rspec in application.rb:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework      :rspec
end
```

then `rails g controller things` will work. Opt not to overwrite files as they're generated.

All a spec looks like when it's generated is the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ThingsController do

  it "should be successful" do
    get :index
    response.should be_successful
  end

end
```

I often create the specs manually, as it's rather trivial.

Comment: I noticed that sometimes the generated tests can be more detailed than that. Especially when you are generating resources, then the test will contain code for all REST methods.

Comment: You specifically said "existing controllers" in your question's title, so I didn't notice you included models in the text.  Either way, rerunning the generator and saying `n` when they ask to overwrite the model or controller file will suit your purposes nicely. :)