# Creating rspec files for existing model (beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a Rails application with one model (following a tutorial) and I forgot to install the gem Rspec at inception. I have now done it but the Spec files and folders don't show up.

I have read the following : [How do I generate specs for existing controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235763/how-do-i-generate-specs-for-existing-controllers)  and tried a few command lines that have generated files (am so noob I cant find out what it has actually done)

But no new Spec files !

Would it be because I have a Model and not a Controller ? What would be the correct command line ? Alternatively may I create them directly and with what name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all delete the `test` directory then run the following command

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

And if you are using bundler then use the following command instead

```
bundle exec rails generate rspec:install
```

It should create a `spec` directory in your rails root

In that directory you should find the following file among other directories `spec_helper.rb`

Then you can edit this file if you needed to

And to run the tests you should use the following command

```
 rspec
```

Or the following if you are using bundler

```
bundle exec rspec
```

Answer (score 52):

Run the generators again:

```
rails generate rspec:model MyModel
rails generate rspec:controller MyController
```

It will ask if you want to override existing files. Answer as appropriate for your situation. You probably want to keep your existing model/controller files. The new controller specs should end up in (for example) `spec/controllers/my_controller_spec.rb`.

Or you can simply add spec files manually. Consult the [rspec-rails documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/gettingstarted) for more details.

I also recommend reading the [Guide to Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html).

Comment: Tried the first one and get Could not find generator rspec:model. Though Bundle Install returns 5 rspec gems (-mocks, -core .. and rspec (3.0.0))

Comment: OK seems I had a reference to 'rspec' in my gemfile as i needed 'rspec-rails'. Now I have both gems installed and rails:generate rspec:install now works. Should I keep reference to both rspec (3.0.0) and rspec-rails (3.0.1) in the gemfile ? any difference between them ?

Comment: `rspec-rails` should install `rspec`, `rspec-mocks`, etc. So you need only include `rspec-rails` in Gemfile; bundler will fetch the appropirate related gems.

Comment: Also, you should probably accept the other answer, not this one :)

Comment: I don't know why I installed rspec first place instead of rspec-rails.. Well two birds one stone. :) many thanks to you and artmees

Comment: Note that the command `rails generate rspec:controller MyController` will append "controller" in the file name viz `rails generate rspec:controller MyController` will create the file `spec/controllers/my_controller_controller_spec.rb` instead of expected `spec/controllers/my_controller_spec.rb`.