# Rails 4 and Rspec - generate controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have an API that has many controllers and models.

I installed Rspec and every new resource I create, the corresponding test files are created automatically.

Is there a way to generate these files for all others old resources including REST tests?

For instance, I have a file costumers_controller.rb created before I install Rspec, is there a way to generate the default file costumers_controller_spec.rb?

Comment: This question has already been answered here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235763/how-do-i-generate-specs-for-existing-controllers

Comment: OK @mjhlobdell, but this only creates a file 'almost empty', I would like to have the code for all REST methods. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
rails g rspec:scaffold controller_name
```

This generate also the request and routing file.

In order to generate the model just use:

```
rails g rspec:model model_name
```

And all test files will be ready to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Generate a controller with simple spec examples for the specified actions:

`rails g rspec:controller Posts index show create`