# Writing the correct rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am a little new to writing tests with rspec and I am trying to figure out how to correctly write this test for this definition. The definition simply searches for the user, and if they are already added, it will not return them. The definition works, I just want to correctly test it.

Here's what I've got in the controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  ROWS = 9
  def name_search
    page = params[:page].present? ? params[:page] : 1
    query = params[:query].present? ? params[:query] : params[:'search-keywords']
    approved_user_ids = Approval.where(user_id: logged_in_user.id).pluck(:approved_user_id)
    search_results = User.where(['name LIKE :query OR operator_id LIKE :query', { query:
                                 "%#{query}%" }]).where.not(id: approved_user_ids).order(:name)
    page_count = (search_results.count / ROWS.to_f).ceil
    paginated_search_results = search_results.limit(ROWS).offset(ROWS * (page.to_i - 1))
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        if request.xhr?
          render partial: 'layouts/search_results_modal', locals: { search_results: paginated_search_results,
                                                                    page_count: page_count, page: page, query: query
                                                                  }, layout: false, status: 200
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and in the test:

```
context 'when a user is added' do
  subject { controller.name_search }
  let(:approved_user) { double(map: double) }

  before do
    allow(controller).to receive(:logged_in_user).with(no_args).and_return(logged_in_user)
    allow(User).to receive(:where).and_return(empty_collection)
  end

  it "name search receieves correct results" do
    expect(Approval).to receive(:where).with( { user_id: logged_in_user.id } ).and_return(approved_user)
    expect(User).to receive(:where).with('name LIKE ? OR operator_id LIKE ?', "%#{ query }%", "%#{ query }%")
    subject
  end 
end
```

Am I on the right path for writing a test for this? Any idea how I can correctly test this definition "name_search"?

Comment: Allow me to point you in a direction. Rails controller are mediums between the client(view) and the app(mostly models). And accessing a controller action is through routes. Knowing this, you should then understand that your controller test is not complete without either a `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`. Answer this: what is the route that leads to the action you are trying to test? send a request to the route....

Comment: See the "[Controller Specs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#controller-specs)" section of the `rspec-rails` readme.

Comment: See also "[How do I generate specs for existing controllers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235763/how-do-i-generate-specs-for-existing-controllers/30808557#30808557)"